# Get image src in both jsx and .css

Tags: reactjs

I have my `images` folder under public folder. I use it in `jsx` like this:

```
<img src="/images/twitter.png" alt="twitter" />
```

This works.

But I have a problem in CSS's `url`.

```
background-image: url(/images/twitter.png); // compiler can't resolve this file.
```

The above doesn't work now. How do I make this work? I am not using webpack and don't want to use it for now.

Comment: I hope the relative path is correct. Try this : `background-image: url(./images/twitter.png);`

Comment: same error . no idea

Comment: Can you post complete error?

Answer (score 0):

Where is your css file located?
Is it in the same folder since you are writing the route identical to your  code?

Answer: Check the route of your img.png relative to your css file. It can be the only problem.